# hierarchical tables or self join - task database schema - microsoft access

Tags: ms-access, hierarchical-data, self-join

I'm setting up an Access database to track costs against project tasks. The tasks are hierarchical - Projects have tasks, tasks have sub-tasks, etc. Tasks correlate with line items on an invoice, but not all tasks are chargeable (they are used to track progress completion as well).

My current data model only has three layers of tasks, but I'd like to set it up to allow infinite layers (within reason). The attached schema is a simplification - I have multiple tasklayer2 & tasklayer3 tables to suit different types of subtasks  .

Is a self joining table a good replacement for the 'Hierarchial Tasks' group or is there a better approach? How would I account for the different subtask fields - add extra fields to the self-join?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest having 1 table for each unique type of task, then a table 
(Lets call it tblProjectJobs) matching tasks to projects, use the unique ID in this table to locate unique tasks. tblProjectJobs should have a column (lets call it "Parent") that is nullable, if "Parent" contains an ID number of another row in tblProjectJobs, we know that the current row is a sub-task of the row indicated in "Parent".

This allows you to nest as long as you like, with whatever task types you like, in whatever order you like. You could also merge the common task fields into tblProjectJobs, leaving only the unique columns that separate the tasks.